# How to use synchronized in callback functions?

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, synchronize

I was trying to learn how to use synchronized to lock the callback function's register. Following is my code, where `run()` is the `register_callback()` function. I used synchronized to lock the register to avoid some callback functions won't be called in the register, but it does not work sometimes. 
My understanding is `run()` lock the register `l` first and detect the flag then do next step. But, sometimes, `run()` will add the value to `l` after the register `l` was traversed in `printList()`, which means the value won't be printed. 
How should I change the code to make sure I can callback all these id?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestThread extends Thread
{
    public static List<Long> l = new ArrayList<>();
    public static boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized (l) {
            if (!flag) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                l.add(Thread.currentThread().getId());
            } else {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printList()
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        flag = true;
        for (long curr : l) {
            System.out.println("list: " + Long.toString(curr) + " " + Integer.toString(l.size()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        TestThread t1 = new TestThread();
        TestThread t2 = new TestThread();
        TestThread t3 = new TestThread();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        TestThread.sleep(5);
        TestThread.printList();

        t3.start();

        TestThread.sleep(50);
        System.out.println(l.size());
        for (long curr : l) {
            System.out.println(curr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after printlist() traversal new code will not added. The list size remains 1 for the end of the code run.
Test it yourself, either by debugging it step by step or put a System.out.println("new value added:")  in the  if(!flag) part or just print the size of the 'l' list at the end of the code

Comment: Writing a thread that does all of its work in one synchronized block is virtually always a mistake.  Threads serve no other purpose except to be able to do different things at the same time, but you have made it impossible for your three threads to run at the same time.

Comment: One of the most important rules of collaborating with other software developers (i.e., what you will have to do if you get employed as a developer) is, "Don't do anything surprising if there's an un-surprising way to accomplish the same thing."  People won't want to read your code if they have to stop and scratch their heads and ask, "Now, why did he call `TestThread.sleep(5)` instead of calling `Thread.sleep(5)`?"  It's the same method call either way, so you're better off calling it in the _obvious_ way.

Comment: P.S., Using `sleep()` to synchronize threads sometimes makes for easy-to-understand demos, but it's not actually guaranteed to work in the real-world.  Plus, it virtually always makes the program take more time to run than it really needs to take.  For example, instead of calling `sleep(50)` to wait for the three threads to finish, your `main()` routine could call `t1.join()`, `t2.join()`, `t3.join()`.  That actually would _guarantee_ that the threads have finished before `main()` went on to perform the final println()s.

Comment: Hi, james. The reason I used sleep was not because I wanna make sure the threads will finish before print(). If the thread runs before `print()`, it should put the value into register, If not it will print it directly.  If I do not use synchronize before if statement, sometime the `run()` will put the value into register after `print()` was called, so the value would never be printed.